# Download Throttle in node.js

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb

I am running a server on node using Connect. The server returns a response of around 50,000 records for a particular request say www.sample.com/service/store_id. once the server receives a request, it interacts with mongoDB to fetch the store details and returns the store details(50,000 records) as response.

I am exposing the URL to a mobile. The mobile user tries to get the response by requesting the URL. The mobile starts to retrieve or download 50,000 records. The download stops when it retrieves around 25,000 records. The mobile user resumes the download after some time. How do i start the download from 25000 to 50000 records as the user already have the first 25000 records?

How can i use download throttle in the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [pagination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination) :)

[Here is how to do it with the mongoDB driver.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056241/pagination-with-mongodb#2062601)